# como añadir mas canales IDS al codigo python

Tags: python

Estoy creando un bot que da la informacion de un canal de youtube en especifico, pero tengo un problema y necesito como añadir mas canales IDS en "if ctx.message.channel.id ==" para poder usar el comando !Youtube en un canal en especifico
Este es el código que estoy usando

```
@bot.command()
async def Youtube(ctx):
    if ctx.message.channel.id == 1028165477782007838:
        
        response = requests.get(f"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={Api_key_Youtube}&channelId={Id_Canal_Youtube}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20")
        video = response.json()["items"][0]["snippet"]["title"]
        id_video_youtube = response.json()["items"][0]["id"]["videoId"]
        await ctx.send(f'{video}\n\n{url_youtube}{id_video_youtube}') 

    else:
        await ctx.send("No puedes usar el comando en este canal")
```

Probe de esta manera
if ctx.message.channel.id == ["1028165477782007838","..."]:
Pero no funciona

Comment: Usa `in` ejemplo `ctx.message.channel.id in [lista de canales]:`

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo he podido solucionar